# Attempting to send ETH from wallet to contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, gas, hardhat

I am attempting to implement a basic token swap in which someone sends Ether to the smart contract and receives Governor Token (GT) in return. The contract is able to send GT however, when sending ETH back to the contract I get the following error message:

```
Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit
```

Can someone please tell me how to solve this?

Here is the function from which the error occurs:

```
    function swapETHForGT(uint256 amount) external payable {
        uint256 tokenAmount = amount * rate * 1000000000000000000;
        require(GT.balanceOf(Governor) >= tokenAmount);

        GT.transferFrom(payable(Governor), payable(msg.sender), tokenAmount);

        (bool sent, bytes memory data) = payable(address(this)).call{value: amount * 1000000000000000000}("");
        require(sent, "tx failed");
    }
```

The function fails when calling ETH. However, the transfer from function works perfectly.

Here is the entirety of the error message:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'tx failed'", method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0xdD2FD4581271e230360230F9337D5c0430Bf44C0","to":"0x3Aa5ebB10DC797CAC828524e59A333d0A371443c","data":"0xdbc151bc0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005","accessList":null}, error={"code":-32603,"message":"Internal JSON-RPC error.","data":{"code":-32603,"message":"Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'tx failed'","data":{"message":"Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'tx 

etc
```

Terminal output is:

```
 Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'tx failed'
      at DAO.swapETHForGT (contracts/DAO.sol:170)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

- use the correct contract address
- add the `{from: <myAddress>}` in order of it to working inside the `.call()`
- check and change the network you account is connected to on the metamask (if used).
- manually set the gasLimit higher than your gas

Comment: How can I set the gasLimit higher for an individual function, I thought setting gasLimit in the hardhat config sets it for contract deployment, am I wrong?

Comment: Yes,  setting gasLimit in the hardhat config sets it for contract deployment, but if a  single function expends more gas resulting in over the gasLimit, the transaction will still fail.